# how to programmatically create actionlink in controller and pass it to webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
Dim gridvalue = masobj.fillauditplanDet(cond)
Dim columns As New List(Of WebGridColumn)()
columns.Add(New WebGridColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Year", .Header = "Year"}) columns.Add(New WebGridColumn() With {.ColumnName = "ID", .Header = "", .Format = Function(model) New HtmlString(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "edit", New With {.ID = item.ID}).ToString())}) 
ViewBag.cols = columns
```

---

```
return PartialView("_WebGrid", gridvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be better to use [tagBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder(v=vs.111).aspx) class:

```
var tb = new TagBuilder("a");
tb.MergeAttribute("href",Url.Action("Edit", "edit", New With {.ID = item.ID}).ToString());
tb.AddCssClass(cssClass);
tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);


columns.Add(New WebGridColumn() With {.ColumnName = "Year", .Header = "Year"}) columns.Add(New WebGridColumn() With {.ColumnName = "ID", .Header = "", .Format = Function(model) tb.ToString(TagRenderMode)})
```